# How to differentiate edpoints with the same name but different query params in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I'm new to spring boot and trying to make a Rest API with some resources, I have the following:

**Get all existing rules**:

```
 @GetMapping("/rules")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all the existing rules", response = RuleViewModel.class) //Swagger documentation
    public  ResponseEntity<Page<RuleViewModel>> get(@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 25) Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Rule> rulesEntity = ruleService.findByDeletedIsSend(false, pageable);
        Page<RuleViewModel> ruleViewModels =  rulesEntity.map(mapper::ruleViewModelMapper);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ruleViewModels, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Filter all the existing rules with different parameters**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/rules")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get a specific rule by filter", response = RuleViewModel.class)
public ResponseEntity<Page<RuleViewModel>> getByFilter(
        @RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) Optional<String> ruleId,
        @RequestParam(name = "description", required = false) Optional<String> description,
        @RequestParam(name = "types", required = false) Optional<List<Boolean>> types,
        @RequestParam(name = "layers", required = false) Optional<List<Layer>> layers,
        @RequestParam(name = "groups", required = false) Optional<List<Category>> groups,
        Pageable pageable
) {
    Page<Rule> rulesEntities = ruleService
            .filterRule(
                    types.orElse(Arrays.asList(true, false)),
                    layers.orElse(layerService.findByIsActive(true)),
                    groups.orElse(categoryService.findByIsActive(true)),
                    description.orElse(""),
                    ruleId.orElse(""),
                    false,
                    pageable
            );
    Page<RuleViewModel> ruleViewModels = rulesEntities.map(mapper::ruleViewModelMapper);
    return ruleViewModels.getSize() > 0 ? new ResponseEntity<>(ruleViewModels, HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

As you can see the path is the same ("/rules") but in the case of the filters, it adds all the optional parameters.

The problem I have is that when I want to use filter params as:

```
http://localhost:5656/v1/rules?id=7be4336d-6495-5b71-9bc2-a97c9da5ede2
```

It always goes to get all rules endpoint.

The workaround I made was to add the "search" path to URI like this:

http://localhost:5656/v1/rules/search?id=7be4336d-6495-5b71-9bc2-a97c9da5ede2

So the requests get correctly mapped, but I think it violates the Rest best practices.

Could you point me in the right way to achieve this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the `params` parameter exists on the mapping annotations for precisely this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both the methods have the same return type and all parameters to the getByFilter method are optional, why don't you remove the getByFilter method and add the parameters as optional parameters to the get method? The get method can then perform the filter logic if any of the optional parameters are passed in, else return the complete response without any filtering.

Comment: Agree. This also plays well with Swagger that's also used in the OP's question.